# Finding the maximum load over a 24 hour period, and keeping row info corresponding to each max value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, forecasting

I am very new at coding and need some guidance. I am attempting to forecast the timing of the daily peak load (hour in which the peak load occurs).
Here is a snapshot of the first day in 2002 data:
During the first hour on January 1, 2002, the average, median, maximum, and minimum temperatures were recorded as 43, 43, 60, and 31 degrees Fahrenheit, respectively. In this same hour, a total of 1,384,494 MWh (megawatt-hours) of electricity load was consumed.

```
Essentially trying to find the maximum values of load per 24 hours and then its corresponding time.So far I have this but it not working.
```

```
max_Load = df3.groupby(df3.index // 24)['Load'].idxmax()
max_df = df3.loc[max_Load.index * 24].reset_index(drop=True)
max_df['max_Load'] = max_Load.valuesmax_df
```

Included in the picture is what it outputs: Max load is way off

Comment: Welcome to SO, please [edit] your question to provide more details. In particular you should provide a clear [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of input/output

Comment: You must add more details and code you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```py
max_Load = df3.groupby(df3.index // 24).idxmax()["Load"]
max_df = df3.loc[max_Load].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Basically `df3.groupby(df3.index // 24).idxmax()` gives you a data frame where the index is the possible values for `df3.index // 24` and the columns are the original columns from your `df3`. The values are the indices of the maximum value for that column for each value of `df.index // 24`. Just take the `"Load"` column of this to get the indices of `df3` where `"Load"` is maximal from each value of `df3.index // 24`.